# How *efficient* is using file_get_contents with Mustache.php compared to just storing HTML in variable?

Tags: php, mustache

I've just started looking into using Mustache.php (after hearing good things about the library). But looking at the documentation it seems like you have to store your HTML template code inside a PHP variable for Mustache to be able to access it - this seems very messy to me so I wanted to find another way to do this (e.g. file_get_contents of a plain .html file).

This is the code I was messing about with...

```
$template = '
  <p>Hello {{name}}</p>
  <p>Sorry, you\'re a {{type}}!</p>
  {{#under_18}}
   <p><strong><u>{{generate_random_stuff}}</u></strong>.<p>
  {{/under_18}}
 ';
```

...and so instead I thought this would be easier for our front-end dev to manage...

```
$template = file_get_contents('template.html');
```

...where 'template.html' contains just...

```
<p>Hello {{name}}</p>
<p>Sorry, you're a {{type}}!</p>
{{#under_18}}
<p><strong><u>{{generate_random_stuff}}</u></strong>.<p>
{{/under_18}}
```

But I wasn't sure how *efficient* using file_get_contents was? compared to storing as a string in a variable? Especially over multiple page views or having multiple template html files on a single page.

Any information you can give me on this sort of stuff I would be grateful.

Comment: I believe this approach is no longer necessary with respect to Mustache.php, since in version 2.0 it actually compiles php code from the initial .html templates.

Answer (score 2):

as i understand it, it is not in Mustache's goal to take responsability of obtaining the template.

You can safely use file_get_contents of local files in your code and won't hit a performance issue before long.

If ever you hit a performance issue (because, for instance, your hard drive is too slow or too busy doing something else), start looking at memory-caching (see memcache or redis for instance) but I am pretty sure you won't hit this bottleneck before long.

Under PHP, you can also take a look at the Smarty templating engine which is very efficient (it pre-compiles templates to php).

I hope this will help you,

Jerome

Comment: Mustache, as of 2.0, precompiles templates to php as well (if you give it a compiled template directory to work with).